# Antenna reception quality

Tags: antenna

When frequency increases size of the antenna needed decreases.

Lets take Marconi antenna:

[image]

Let λ is the wavelength, it seems an antenna length of λ/2 is adequate for good reception.

My question is, if size of λ/2 is adequate in above case. is a size of N x (λ/2) has even better reception than λ/2 size (N is integer)? And why?

**For the antenna above if we plot the antenna size in terms of λ versus the received power how would it look like?**

Comment: I know very little of RF but I have something like 5/8 lambda bouncing around in my head.

Comment: I was thinking the longer this antenna the more current induced in it. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Of such requirements are antenna-tuning-boxes used.

Comment: I read the first sentence twice, and it still doesn't make sense.  I'm not gonna read the rest.  Try again in English.

Comment: @user1234 You are indeed wrong. As your antenna gets longer, current induced in different parts of it will cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

Longer antennas have radiation patterns that put more power in some directions at the expense of power in other directions. These are often described as peaks and nulls. Not what you want in a general-coverage antenna, but for a specific point-to-point communication path, a peak might be pointed in a desired direction. 
Yes, these longer antennas have gain ( the 2 wavelength antenna has *peak* gain over a half-wavelength antenna) in some directions. These ideal patterns are for antennas in free-space, unaffected by ground or nearby objects:
[image: directivity of longer antennas]
image from:[Electrical Communication A.L.Albert](http://www.vias.org/albert_ecomm/aec12_radio_wave_propagation_018.html)

Comment: I was searching for that great picture but you found it +1. Where?

Comment: @Andyaka apologies: attribution added.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the corrections. The picture in your question is a monopole antenna i.e. half a dipole and it has a length of \$\lambda /4\$. The picture shows how a monopole (unbalanced antenna) is visualized from the standard dipole antenna. Marconi used a \$\lambda /4\$ monopole.

So, assuming you are referring to a monopole, if you double the length to \$\lambda/2\$, the output impedance goes through the roof and it becomes difficult to extract a signal compared to operating it at \$\lambda /4\$.

Then, if you added another \$\lambda /4\$ to the \$\lambda/2\$ you are  making a \$3\lambda/4\$ antenna. Take a look at the impedance of a monopole at 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75 \$\lambda\$.

[image]

- At 0.25 \$\lambda\$ impedance is about 37 ohms and their is no reactive component.
- At 0.5 \$\lambda\$ impedance is about 1200 ohm resistive in series with about 1200 ohms capacitive reactance.
- At 0.75 \$\lambda\$ things are very similar to 0.25 \$\lambda\$ and power extraction is simple.

But maybe you get more signal at 0.75 \$\lambda\$? Not really but, you do get interesting radiation patterns forming and these form because you are trying to extract power from an antenna that is too long and you get induction to other parts of the antenna that form the odd shaped radiation patterns. I would urge you to look at the various radiation patterns for a dipole antenna found on [this](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/dipole.php) site.

Here also is a picture of dipole being extendedto twice length and how 4 lobes are produced. The picture then goes on to "imply" the reasoning behind the folded dipole: -

[image]

And finally, after trying to find the picture in Glen's answer I found this: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.w6si.com/blog-009.html)

Comment: 0.625! there is my 5/8 lambda!

Comment: @oldfart and very nice it is!

Answer (score 0):

Feedpoint impedance aside, another consequence of using a full-wave dipole vs. a λ/2 dipole is that a full-wave dipole has a deep null ±90° to the plane of its physical orientation, whereas the λ/2 dipole has peak *gain* (directivity) in those directions.

The same is true for a Marconi antenna.